# How to see the times statements take to be executed in a stored procedure DB2

Tags: database, db2

i'm trying to increase the performance of a query - Stored procedure in DB2 that scans a lot of tables and a lot of selects.

What i am trying to do is to find which of these statements (insert select statements) lasts more and how time it takes each to be completed.

Comment: What is your Db2-server PLATFORM (Z/OS, i series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud, as this determines the tooling available for profiling.  Also please use the correct tags for Db2-server platform.  Specify the Db2-server version also (again, tooling can be version specific).

Comment: IBM Data studio version 4.1.4 (with latest fixes) also has tooling to let you profile stored procedures.

Comment: @mao hello, i will try Data Studio  (IBM) On monday and i will come back with results. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If static statements have been run by the routine are still in the package cache, then:

```
SELECT 
  S.STMTNO -- Line number in SP
, P.NUM_EXEC_WITH_METRICS
, P.STMT_EXEC_TIME
-- Huge number of other counters from the package cache here:
--, P.* 
, P.STMT_TEXT
FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES R
JOIN SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP D ON (D.ROUTINESCHEMA, D.SPECIFICNAME, D.BTYPE) = (R.ROUTINESCHEMA, R.SPECIFICNAME, 'K')
JOIN SYSCAT.STATEMENTS S ON (S.PKGSCHEMA, S.PKGNAME) = (D.BSCHEMA, D.BNAME)
LEFT JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, NULL, NULL, -2)) P ON 
  (P.PACKAGE_SCHEMA, P.PACKAGE_NAME, P.PACKAGE_VERSION_ID, P.SECTION_NUMBER) 
= (D.BSCHEMA, D.BNAME, S.VERSION, S.SECTNO)
WHERE 
--(R.ROUTINESCHEMA, R.ROUTINENAME) = ('MY_ROUTINE_SCHEMA', 'MY_ROUTINE_NAME')
(R.ROUTINESCHEMA, R.SPECIFICNAME) = ('MY_ROUTINE_SCHEMA', 'MY_ROUTINE_SPECIFICNAME')
ORDER BY P.STMT_EXEC_TIME DESC
```

No way to bound dynamic statements from the package cache to some routine.
That is, if your routine runs some dynamic statements, you may find the corresponding statistics in the case only manually, say, comparing the statement texts visually / manually...

**Update: Event monitor for activities use**
[CREATE EVENT MONITOR (activities) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-event-monitor-activities)
An event monitor for activities acts as a "logger" for statements. You may turn it on temporarily for some session, for example.

```
-- Creation
CREATE EVENT MONITOR ACT FOR ACTIVITIES 
WRITE TO TABLE
  ACTIVITY        (TABLE ACTIVITY_ACT        IN SYSTOOLSPACE)
, ACTIVITYMETRICS (TABLE ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT IN SYSTOOLSPACE)
, ACTIVITYSTMT    (TABLE ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT    IN SYSTOOLSPACE)
, ACTIVITYVALS    (TABLE ACTIVITYVALS_ACT    IN SYSTOOLSPACE)
, CONTROL         (TABLE CONTROL_ACT         IN SYSTOOLSPACE)
MANUALSTART
;

-- Start the event monitor
SET EVENT MONITOR ACT STATE 1;

-- Turn the collection on for your current session
CALL WLM_SET_CONN_ENV(MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE(), '<collectactdata>WITH DETAILS AND VALUES</collectactdata>');

-- Run your statement(s)
CALL MY_ROUTINE ...;

-- Turn the collection off for your current session
CALL WLM_SET_CONN_ENV(MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE(), '<collectactdata>NONE</collectactdata>');

-- Stop the event monitor (optionally)
SET EVENT MONITOR ACT STATE 0;

-- Analysis
SELECT 
  A.TIME_STARTED, A.TIME_COMPLETED
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(A.TIME_COMPLETED - A.TIME_STARTED)) TIME_S
, A.ADDRESS, A.APPL_NAME, A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID
--, V.STMT_VALUE_INDEX, V.STMT_VALUE_ISREOPT
--, V.STMT_VALUE_INDEX, VARCHAR(V.STMT_VALUE_DATA, 50) STMT_VALUE_DATA
, S.CREATOR, S.PACKAGE_NAME
, S.STMTNO -- Line number in SP
, M.STMT_EXEC_TIME, M.TOTAL_ACT_WAIT_TIME
, 100 * M.TOTAL_ACT_WAIT_TIME / NULLIF (M.STMT_EXEC_TIME, 0) AS WAIT_PST
, M.ROWS_READ, M.ROWS_RETURNED, M.ROWS_MODIFIED
-- Other metrics if needed
-- , M.*
, VARCHAR(S.STMT_TEXT, 256) stmt_text
FROM ACTIVITY_ACT A
JOIN ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT S ON 
  (S.PARTITION_NUMBER, S.APPL_ID, S.UOW_ID, S.ACTIVITY_ID, S.ACTIVITY_SECONDARY_ID) 
= (A.PARTITION_NUMBER, A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID, A.ACTIVITY_SECONDARY_ID)
JOIN ACTIVITYMETRICS_ACT M ON 
  (M.PARTITION_NUMBER, M.APPL_ID, M.UOW_ID, M.ACTIVITY_ID, M.ACTIVITY_SECONDARY_ID) 
= (A.PARTITION_NUMBER, A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID, A.ACTIVITY_SECONDARY_ID)
/*
-- Statement parameters
LEFT JOIN ACTIVITYVALS_ACT V ON 
  (V.PARTITION_NUMBER, V.APPL_ID, S.UOW_ID, V.ACTIVITY_ID, V.ACTIVITY_SECONDARY_ID) 
= (A.PARTITION_NUMBER, A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID, A.ACTIVITY_SECONDARY_ID)
*/
WHERE A.APPL_ID = MON_GET_APPLICATION_ID ()
ORDER BY A.TIME_STARTED, A.APPL_ID, A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID;
```

Refer to the [Logical data groups and event monitor output tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tables-logical-data-groups-event-monitor-output) link for the description of event monitor tables and their contents.

Comment: There is another technique - to catch all the routine statements into the event monitor for activities tables. All routine statements (both dynamic and static) can be found there.

Comment: hello, as it seems there is no event with such name and thus i need to create one. any idea on how i can create an event monitor for my problem because ibm documentation is a mess?

Comment: [CREATE EVENT MONITOR (activities) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-event-monitor-activities). I'll update the answer with an example on this.

Comment: Thank you for answering that fast. i'll see your example and produce my solution on this!

Comment: one last question in here, my routine will run for over than 4 hours and thus do i need to wait 4 hours to stop the event monitor or i may stop it immediately ?

Comment: The event monitor must be turned on during all run time of the routine. You don't have to stop the event monitor at the end. It's like debug logging. Don't forget to turn it off eventually, if you don't need it anymore to avoid unanticipated growth of the event monitor tables.

Comment: hello again! after running the query and selecting the above query for results after 6 seconds of running it crashes the whole session. Any idea on that?

Comment: "Crashes the whole session" statement means nothing to understand the root cause of the problem. What's the error message you got on this query?

Comment: screen freezes and i'm unable to do anything regarding the specific session. i need to close the program through task manager. Query is running meanwhile the screen freezes.

Comment: It's hard to say why it hangs in your case. It may be because of large number of rows in the event monitor tables or some locking issue, when evm writes to the tables when you try to read them. You may try to stop the event monitor and index all tables by, say `APPL_ID` and collect statistics (that is `CREATE INDEX <TABNAME>_APPL_ID ON <TABNAME> (APPL_ID)`, `CALL ADMIN_CMD ('RUNSTATS ON TABLE <TABNAME> AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL')`, where `<TABNAME>` - every table participating in the query. Then start event monitor and run the query again with `WITH UR` clause at the end.

Comment: hello again issue closed. after some hours it unfreezed itself and i could see everything as you mentioned. thanks for your help you're highly appreciated!!!